# Mix of Cyclic and Chained MySQL replication - What do you do with "log-slave-updates"..?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have the following MySQL replication topology set up:

- Master1 (M1) replicates to Master2 (M2)
- Master2 (M2) replicates to Master1 (M1)
- Master1 (M1) replicates to Slave1 (S1)

Pictorial View

```
+<------------+
|             ^
|             |
V             |
M1----------> M2
|
+-----------> S1
```

All users connect to their masters for selects and updates.

The theory in the cyclic replication is that if I need to do any maintenance on the Master, I can point everyone temporarily at Slave 1 whilst I do the work, and then when Master is back online and the changes have been replicated from `M2`, I can seamlessly swap everyone back to working on the Master.

S1 is an offsite server in case of a local disaster, so does not need the cyclic replication set up.

The problem I currently have is that any changes made on `M2` are not replicating to `S1`, so in the scenario above where I do need to take the master offline, any changes which get made on `M2` in the meantime, will not make it to the offsite copy on `S1`.

I understand I can set the flag "log-slave-updates" on Master which would then cause changes made on `M2` and pushed to Master as part of the replication, to be passed to `S1` but I am nervous, that with the cyclic replication in place between `M1` and `M2`, that this will also, in some way try and push the same changes back to `M2` again and end up in an endless loop of replication.

I am guessing that MySQL is clever enough to handle this, but can someone help guide me towards anything I may need to consider in this situation before I end up in an infinite loop of replication!!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are absolutely right to be concerned about `log-slave-updates` causing an issue with your Master-Master setup, though it won't necessarily be an infinite loop changes. I suspect *if you are writing to both masters*, that you will constantly be having to set `skip_slave_counter` and restart the slave thread.... In a word, not ideal.

I would look over [this post](http://www.webaugur.com/webdev/19-mysql-master-master-slave-s-database-replication.html), specifically the short section on data integrity:

> The safest solution is to simply never write data to both masters.

So, if both master's are up, but your clients only ever write to one master at a time (Master 1 by default), then you *shouldn't* have an issue.

---

*shouldn't doesn't mean you won't, though.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have clients writing to two different masters. The second "master" is really a slave and would not have any direct client access - unless I need to take the primary master down for maintenance.

I think actually, I would set the the secondary master up with log-slave-updates and make the slave slave from that, as then I would not need to wait for the slave to catch up again when I bring the primary master back on line - if you see what I mean?

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

log_slave_updates = 1 -- all machines

sync_binlog = 1 -- if it is not too slow.

server_id -- different on every machine

Don't write to both masters, you are asking for trouble.  Instead, leave one Master as a hot standby.  (You get no performance boost anyway, since all writes have to be done on all machines.)

Simpler Ascii picture:  S1 <- M1 <-> M2

Arrange for all clients to connect via hostname or some kind of "virtual" host name (eg, DNS).  Don't use sockets.